# regular expression to match current and coming years?

Tags: regex

I have years as follows:

```
1999
1985
2013
2014
2007
2016
2050
```

How can I select only current and coming years using regex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\b20(?:1[4-9]|[2-9]\d)\b
```

Will match years `2014` to `2099`. [Explanation here](http://regex101.com/r/dO4rS8).

Alternately, this regex should match *any* years above and including `2014` (e.g. `2037`, `2999`, `318765`):

```
\b(?:2\d(?:1[4-9]|[2-9]\d)|\d{5,}|[3-9]\d{3,})\b
```

[Explanation here](http://regex101.com/r/nY2yK2).

Answer (score 0):

First thing coming to my mind...

`(201[3-9])|(20[2-9][0-9])|(2[1-9][0-9][0-9])`

Matches 2013-2999. Apply capturing groups as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
 ([3-9][0-9]{3,})|(201[3-9])|(20[2-9][0-9])|(2[1-9][0-9][0-9])
```